# How to parse and find the next 'td' after specific text in HTML

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have taken a subset of approximately 1850 html articles in a database and tried to parse through them to find four (4) qualifiers: Equipment ID, Location, Inspector, and Comments.  I have two solutions that are getting me part way there, but I am having trouble with the last component which is to loop through the data and return the unique information (4 qualifiers) for each of the articles.  Please scroll to bottom for subset.

This code provides unique information for one qualifier-->

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "badhtmlsubset.txt"
hand = open(fname).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(hand, "html.parser")

i = 1
for stuff in soup.findAll(text="Equipment ID:"):
    print i
    print "Equipment ID:", stuff.findNext('td').text,
    #print "Location", stuff.find(text="Location:").findNext('td')   <--Traceback TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

    i = i + 1
```

This code returns the following but I can't get Location, Inspector, or Comments to follow suit.
Equipment ID: V-2 3
Equipment ID: Well 79

This code prints out the correct format, but just repeats the same information over and over and is not unique.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "badhtmlsubset.txt"
hand = open(fname).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(hand, "html.parser")

#This code prints out the correct format, but does not print unique information for each loop. Just repeats the same information over and over.
i=1
for stuff in soup.findAll(text="Equipment ID:"):
    print "Count=", i
    equipid = soup.find(text="Equipment ID:").findNext('td')
    location = soup.find(text="Location:").findNext('td')
    inspector = soup.find(text="Inspector:").findNext('td')
    body = soup.find(text="Comments:").findNext('td')
    print "Equipment ID:", equipid.text,"Location:", location.text,"Inspector:", inspector.text
    print "Comments:", body.text
    i = i + 1
```

I am expecting to get the following output for the iterative data:

```
Equipment ID: Well 53
Location: NMWSS
Inspector: Bob Bobberson
Comments: THE SHELL AND BOTTOM HEAD HAVE PITTING AND GENERAL CORROSION THAT IS BELOW
          THE T MIN FOR THE DESIGN PRESSURE OF THIS VESSEL AS AN ALTERNATIVE TO KEEP THE
          VESSEL IN SERVICE A NEW T MIN FOR THE SHELL AND HEADS CAN BE ASSUMED. THE
          DEEPEST PITS COULD BE REPAIRED AND THE SHELL T MIN SET AT
          0.400&Eacute;?&ugrave; AND THE BOTTOM HEAD T MIN SET AT 0.640&Eacute;?&ugrave;
          WHICH WOULD GIVE A SLIGHT AMOUNT OF CORROSION ALLOWANCE. AT THESE NEW VALUES
          THE VESSEL COULD BE OPERATED AT 92 PSI MAWP. THIS WOULD BE AT THE OWNERS
          DISCRETION. IT APPEARS THAT THE PRV ON THIS VESSEL IS SET AT 50 PSI.
```

The subset here represents 2 articles:

I named this badhtmlsubset.txt

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  "

  <p text-align:=""><img src="" alt="" panfee="" softenever="" width="" height="" /></p>

  <table width:="" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width:="">Field:</td>

        <td>Pan Fee</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Location:</td>

        <td>NMWSS</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Equipment ID:</td>

        <td>V-2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Date:</td>

        <td>07/17/2009</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Inspector:</td>

        <td>Ray Rankin</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td rowspan="">Report(s):</td>

        <td>
          <p>{rsfiles
          path=""data/pan_fee/field/api510/softener_v_2/2009/v2_summary_071709.pdf""}</p>

          <p>{rsfiles
          path=""data/pan_fee/field/api510/softener_v_2/2009/v2_data_071709.pdf""}</p>

          <p>{rsfiles path=""data/pan_fee/field/api510/softener_v_2/2009/v1_calcs.pdf""}
          (same calcs as V-1)</p>

          <p>{rsfiles
          path=""data/pan_fee/field/api510/softener_v_2/2009/v2_acad_071709.pdf""}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>{rsfiles
        path=""data/pan_fee/field/api510/softener_v_2/2009/v2_u1a.pdf""}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>{rsfiles
        path=""data/pan_fee/field/api510/softener_v_2/2009/panfee_v2_ticketclosed_012010.pdf""}</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Comments:</td>

        <td>
          <p>THE SHELL AND BOTTOM HEAD HAVE PITTING AND GENERAL CORROSION THAT IS BELOW
          THE T MIN FOR THE DESIGN PRESSURE OF THIS VESSEL AS AN ALTERNATIVE TO KEEP THE
          VESSEL IN SERVICE A NEW T MIN FOR THE SHELL AND HEADS CAN BE ASSUMED. THE
          DEEPEST PITS COULD BE REPAIRED AND THE SHELL T MIN SET AT
          0.400&Eacute;?&ugrave; AND THE BOTTOM HEAD T MIN SET AT 0.640&Eacute;?&ugrave;
          WHICH WOULD GIVE A SLIGHT AMOUNT OF CORROSION ALLOWANCE. AT THESE NEW VALUES
          THE VESSEL COULD BE OPERATED AT 92 PSI MAWP. THIS WOULD BE AT THE OWNERS
          DISCRETION. IT APPEARS THAT THE PRV ON THIS VESSEL IS SET AT 50 PSI.<br />
          <br />
          FOR FULL CODE COMPLIANCE THE VESSEL SHALL BE DE-RATED IN ACCORDANCE WITH THE
          CALIFORNIA OCCUPOATIONAL SAFETY - PRESSURE VESSEL UNIT <a href="" target=
          "">CIRCULAR LETTER PV-2006-2</a> AND <a href="" target="">CIRCULAR LETTER
          PV-2001-1</a>.</p>

          <p>&nbsp;</p>

          <p><strong color:="">OUT OF SERVICE, TYE HAMMOND, 10/05/2009</strong></p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>UltraPipe Unit ID</td>

        <td>PAN FEE</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>UltraPipe Circuit ID</td>

        <td>7888</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>" "

  <p text-align:=""><img src="" border="border" /></p>

  <p text-align:="">?&#711;</p>

  <p text-align:=""><strong>Please select the desired piping, at the Ethel D location,
  from the submenu.</strong><br />
  <span class="">(future location of data - added for presentation)</span></p>

  <p text-align:="">?&#711;</p>

  <h2 text-align:=""><span class="">There are <strong class="">134</strong> active wells
  listed with DOGGR.</span></h2>" "

  <div text-align:="">
    {vsig}/etheld/api570/flowlines/well_79_fl/2014{/vsig}
  </div>

  <p text-align:="">&nbsp;</p>

  <table width:="" border="1">
    <tbody text-align:="">
      <tr text-align:="">
        <td width:="" text-align:="">Field:</td>

        <td text-align:="">Ethel D</td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">Location:</td>

        <td text-align:="">SMWSS</td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">Equipment ID:</td>

        <td text-align:="">Well 79</td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">Inspection Dates:</td>

        <td text-align:="">Last: 07/30/2014 - Next: 07/30/2019</td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">Inspector:</td>

        <td text-align:="">Ronnie Harleston</td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="" rowspan="">Report(s):</td>

        <td text-align:="">
          <p><strong><span text-decoration:="">2014 INSPECTION
          DATA:</span></strong><br />
          {rsfiles
          path=""data/etheld/api570/flowlines/well79/2014/etheld_well79_flowline_report_073014.pdf""}</p>

          <p>{rsfiles
          path=""data/etheld/api570/flowlines/well79/2014/etheld_well79_flowline_ultrapipe_073014.pdf""}</p>

          <p>{rsfiles
          path=""data/etheld/api570/flowlines/well79/2014/etheld_well79_flowline_field_drawing_073014.pdf""}<br />

          <br />
          <strong><span text-decoration:="">2009 INSPECTION DATA:</span></strong><br />
          {rsfiles
          path=""data/etheld/api570/flowlines/well79/2009/well79_summary_073009.pdf""}<br title=""
          inspection="" /></p>

          <p>{rsfiles
          path=""data/etheld/api570/flowlines/well79/2009/well79_data_073009.pdf""}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">Find in <a href="" target="">Virtual Tour</a></td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">Comments:</td>

        <td text-align:="">
          <p><span text-decoration:=""><strong>Ultrasonic A-Scan Thickness
          Inspection:</strong></span><br />
          Ultrasonic A-Scan thickness measurements were completed in accordance with
          Applus RTD established procedures. 3 thickness measurement locations (TMLs)
          were established and thickness measurements were taken at these locations. All
          thickness readings have been entered into Ultra Pipe and after review of the
          data next inspection will be 07/30/2019. The predicted retirement date of the
          circuit is 07/30/2033 based on calculated corrosion rates and a 2 mil per year
          default corrosion rate. There are 0 caution TMLs per the current thickness
          survey taken on 07/30/2014.</p>

          <p><br />
          <span text-decoration:=""><strong>API 570 Visual
          Inspection:</strong></span></p>

          <p>Visual inspection found this piping circuit to be in fair condition. This
          piping circuit externally is insulated. The insulation is found to be in poor
          condition, with missing or damage insulation, and in the areas the insulation
          is missing the surface condition of the piping is covered with light to
          moderate surface rust. The piping supports surface was covered with light to
          moderate surface rust and no corrosion was present. Support hangers were found
          to be in fair condition. The piping was inspected for code compliance issues
          and to identify possible leaks, stresses and any condition that might reduce
          the life of the piping circuit. All piping will be put on a maximum 5 year
          thickness inspection interval per API (class 2 piping) requirements. Some
          piping TML locations may require re-inspection prior to the maximum interval.
          See UltraPIPE data reports for all required inspection dates.</p>

          <p><br />
          Recommendations: Repair insulation as needed.</p>

          <p>All piping will require an API 570 Visual inspection in 5 years.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">UltraPipe Unit ID</td>

        <td text-align:="">ETHEL_D</td>
      </tr>

      <tr text-align:="">
        <td text-align:="">UltraPipe Circut ID</td>

        <td text-align:="">WELL 79</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>

  <p text-align:="">&nbsp;</p>

  <p>&nbsp;</p>" beautifulsoup html-parsing
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *this code prints out the correct format, but does not print unique information for each loop. Just repeats the same information over and over.* of course it does as you keep calling `soup.find(...` in the loop. A a proper sample of html and what you expect as output

Comment: I went and cleaned the html as well as clearly defined the output.  I have nearly 1900 html articles pulled from a database that are a mess.  I am tryhing ot clean all of the database, but I am STILL stuck on how best to iterate through 200K lines of code, and get the information i need.

Comment: **UPDATE** I am attempting to build a list of iterative dictionaries that contains EquipID, Location, Inspector, Comments, etc...